# Want to use IF THEN

Tags: sql

I need to ID/tag all contact records of our active clients, even if only **one** of the client's contact records is tagged as `ACTIVE`.

Specifically, I want to pull all contact records from all companies in my GoldMine database in which **any one** of the company's contact records has the company's account status tagged as `ACTIVE CLIENT`. Then I plan to take the SQL output, create a group, taking all the contact records from this list and replace the company's account status field from `blank or null` to `ACTIVE CLIENT`.

Comment: Can you give more details about your table structure? What flavour of SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it sounds like you have a list of active clients (companies) and in addition you have a list of all the contacts (people) for a particular client (company).

It seems that you want to take all contacts (people) for a particular client (company) and update an account status column to "active client" for all of those contacts (people) for that particular client (company)- so long as **at least one** of the contacts (people) for that client (company) has its account status column as "active client".

if these are the correct requirements, then you could do this:

```
UPDATE Contacts

SET Account_Status = 'ACTIVE CLIENT'

WHERE Client_ID IN (SELECT Client_ID
    FROM Contacts
    WHERE Account_Status = 'ACTIVE CLIENT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want something that amounts to something like this?

```
UPDATE Company
SET active = 1
WHERE CompanyID IN (
    SELECT
        Client_CompanyID
    FROM
        Contacts          -- or do you mean clients?
    WHERE
        IsActive = 1
)
```

?

If not, pleas let us know what, other than that, you want.

And please, oh please, don't say "and this has to work in MySQL 3.x or 4.x."